# Параметры ссылки

Tags: php

Есть ссылка:

```
domain.ru/loginvk#option1=qwe&option2=asd&option3=zxc
```

Как занести значения **`option1`**, **`option2`**, **`option3`** в одноимённые переменные?

Comment: Интересный вопрос... Без javascript тут каши не сварить, так как php не видит `#option1=qwe&option2=asd&option3=zxc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Могу предложить такую магию, средствами javascript отправляем содержимое location.hash ajax'ом на сервер, парсим строку, возвращаем результат. Готовое решение простите писать не буду.

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = 'domain.ru/loginvk#option1=qwe&option2=asd&option3=zxc';
$params = parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_FRAGMENT));
```

Не совсем в переменные, но, думаю, ассоциативный массив тоже сойдёт. В крайнем случае используйте eval (хотя, всё-таки, постарайтесь так не делать).

- [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)
- [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

Comment: От себя задам вопрос, каким чудом передать в переменную $url все что находится после знака # не прописывая это дело руками?

Comment: А как быть, если эти параметры всегда разные и я не могу точно указать переменную
    $url

Comment: @KRAFT, а откуда вообще вы эту строку берёте? Я ведь точное значение `$url` указал так, для примера.

Comment: @Palmervan +++
Эти параметры генерируются на другой странице, после которой идёт редирект на **`domain.ru/loginvk#option1=qwe&option2=asd&option3=zxc`**

И мне каким-то образом нужно парсить эти данные.

Comment: @fori1ton Сайт `A` генерит эти параметры и делает редирект на мой сайт (сайт `B`), где по задумке автора сайта `A` я должен руками копировать эти данные. Но я не хочу этого делать и нужно придумать способ, который будет это делать за меня.

Comment: @KAFT, URL страницы, на которую вы редиректнулись в PHP можно получить следующим выражением:

    $url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

Comment: @fori1ton Вам неуд!

Comment: Святые угодники!
Да я знаю на какой я странице. :-)

Проблема в том, что `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` не передаст параметры после `**#**`.

Это не `**$_GET**` параметры.

   domain.ru/loginvk#option1=qwe&option2=asd&option3=zxc
   domain.ru/loginvk?option1=qwe&option2=asd&option3=zxc

Comment: В таком случае вы ничего сделать не сможете. Строка после # существует только на стороне клиента и не передаётся на сервер. Пообщайтесь с владельцем сайта A, объясните ему ситуацию, пусть передаёт через GET-параметры.

Answer (score 0):

[`parse_str`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-str.php)`(`[`parse_url`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-url.php)`("domain.ru/loginvk#option1=qwe&option2=asd&option3=zxc")["fragment"]));`